# How do I make this linear-gradient cross-browser?

Tags: css

```
background: -moz-linear-gradient(center bottom , #303030, #3A3A3A) repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
```

I tried `background:-webkit-linear-gradient (center bottom , #303030, #3A3A3A) repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;`
 
          for chrome, but it didn't work. Likewise for IE, I tried `ms-linear-gradient` with the same values, it it didn't work as well.

Comment: First, have you looked at this [**tool**](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/)?

Comment: Really?? It took me two seconds to google it... top three hits on even the vaguest keywords work: http://bit.ly/NyGuFL

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know that colorzilla has an option to import our own CSS. Apologies.

Comment: Okay chill.. I made a mistake. I searched for `linear-gradient` .. 
I didn't know colorzilla has an option to import our own CSS. Apologies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an excellent tool available for generating css for gradients here:

http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

For other css3 you can use:
http://www.css3generator.com/

Answer (score 1):

Either use [this awesome gradient app](http://www.gradientapp.com/) or use [css3please.com](http://css3please.com).

Answer (score 0):

Know that the `linear-gradient` syntax has recently changed:

- keywords for starting points (`center`, `bottom`) have been changed into end points, prefixed with the "to" keyword (`to center`, `to botom`);
- angles now start with 0 at the top of the circle and go clockwise.

MSIE10 will support the new syntax when you omit the prefix.